# Identify Web Server vulnerabilities using cookies

Tags: security, cookies

This was an exam question that asked from us by the course provider. The question was Is it possible to recognize vulnerabilities of a web server by using a cookie installed on the computer? This is a general question. Please answer if you know.

Answer (score 0):

In short - Yes.

During recon and scanning periods of a penetration tests, it's quite often valuable to check what cookies are being saved as they provide a wide attack vector.

For example attacks such as CSRF attacks may be leveraged from an insecure authentication cookie.